# Data directly store to mysql database without any validation already set using php

Tags: php, mysql, validation

I am novice for the php and mysql. cuurrently I'm  working on a registration system using php and mysql to storing the data. So I already connect the database, and I'm doing some validation for the form information the user fill in. I decided not to use html "required" function. But the validation is not working at all. Although the info fill in is empty, it doesn't display any error but it still can proceed to the next step and insert the info to the database. Any help would be appreciated,see whether where is going wrong...

here is my code.

```
<div id="content">
    <form action="signup.php"method="POST">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Sign up your Watevershit account to unlock more shit!</legend>


            <p>
            <label>
                <span>Username :</span>
                <input type="text"name="username">
            </label>
            </p>

            <p><?php if(isset($errors['username1']) echo $errors['username1'])?></p>


            <p>
            <label>
              <span>Password</span>
              <input type="password"name="password">
            </label>
            </p>
            <p><?php if(isset($errors['password1']) echo $errors['password1'])?></p>

            <p>
            <label>
                <span>Confirm Password :</span><input type="password"name="password">
            </label>
            </p>

            <p>
            <label>
                <span>Email:</span>
                <input type="email"name="email">
            </label>
            </p>
            <p><?php if(isset($errors['email1']) echo $errors['email1'])?></p>

            <p>
            <label>
                <input type="submit"id="submit"value="Sign Up Now!">
            </label>
            </p>

            <p>
            <label>
                <span><a href="login.html">Already member?Log in here</a></span>
            </label>
            </p>
        </fieldset>

    </form>

</div>
```

here is my php script which I do all the validation already,but it doesn't work and insert data to database although the form fill in nothing. So,what's wrong here ?

```
<?php
include ('config.php');

//declare variables
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
$email=$_POST['email'];

//define error variables
$usernameERR = $emailERR =$passwordERR="";
$username=$email=$password="";

    //validation

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    //not empty
    //at least 3 characters long


    //start the validation

    //check the username
    if(empty($_POST['username'])){
        $errors['username1'] = "Required fields"
    }

    if (strlen($username) <3   ) {
        $errors['username2'] ="Username must at least 3 characrters long.";
        }

    //check the password
    if (empty($_POST['password'])){
        $errors['password1'] ="Required fields";
    }

    if (strlen($password) < 8) {
        $errors['password2'] = "Password must be 8 characrters long";
    }


    //check the email
    if (empty($_POST['email'])){
        $errors['email1'] = "Required fields";
    }

    if (strlen($email) < 12){
        $errors['email2'] ="Email must at least 12 characrters long";
    }

    //check the errors
    if(count($errors) == 0){
        //redirect to sucess page
        header('Location:login.html');
    }
}


// if all correct,insert data to the database

$query="INSERT INTO user(Username,Password,Email) VALUES ('".$_POST['username']."','".$_POST['password']."','".$_POST['email']."')";
mysqli_query($con,$query);


?>
```

Any idea?

Comment: Never ever store user password without hashing and salting in your database. And you should use prepared statements instead of inserting your values directly to the query, and if not you at least should escape the values.

Comment: ok..but what is problem that all the validation is doesnt work here??i already set all the validation in php script here,but none of them is showing out.can pls help?? @t.niese

Comment: @t.niese - I agree, excellent advice.  Nonetheless he has a good start and will pick up on these pesky security issues with time.

Comment: It will always insert to the database, as you don't check if any error occurred wen calling `mysqli_query`, `header('Location:login.html')` does not abort your script it just tells the browser to do a redirect, the query will still be executed.

Comment: @t.niese so how can i check any error occurred for that issue??if/else statement to check that??or something else???

Comment: @t.niese wat can i do to make all the validation works and display??is it my validation got problem or what??

Comment: You have double quotes AND single quotes surrounding the variables in your query, I would maybe try removing the double quotes they are not necessary. And as soon as this works, do look into http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php to escape the data before insertion, this is a VERY important step that will prevent SQL injections (https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this..**

```
    <?php        
    $errors=array();
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
      $username=$_POST['username'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
        //not empty
        //at least 3 characters long


        //start the validation

        //check the username
        if(empty($_POST['username'])){
            $errors['username1'] = "Required fields";
        }

        if (strlen($username) <3   ) {
            $errors['username2'] ="Username must at least 3 characrters long.";
            }

        //check the password
        if (empty($_POST['password'])){
            $errors['password1'] ="Required fields";
        }

        if (strlen($password) < 8) {
            $errors['password2'] = "Password must be 8 characrters long";
        }


        //check the email
        if (empty($_POST['email'])){
            $errors['email1'] = "Required fields";
        }

        if (strlen($email) < 12){
            $errors['email2'] ="Email must at least 12 characrters long";
        }

        //check the errors
        if(count($errors) == 0){
            $query="INSERT INTO user(Username,Password,Email) VALUES ('".$_POST['username']."','".$_POST['password']."','".$_POST['email']."')";
mysqli_query($con,$query);

        }
    }
    ?>
    <div id="content">
        <form action="" method="POST">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Sign up your Watevershit account to unlock more shit!</legend>


                <p>
                <label>
                    <span>Username :</span>
                    <input type="text"name="username">
                </label>
                </p>

                <p><?php if(!empty($errors['username1'])) { echo $errors['username1']; } ?></p>


                <p>
                <label>
                  <span>Password</span>
                  <input type="password" name="password">
                </label>
                </p>
                <p><?php if(!empty($errors['password1'])) { echo $errors['password1']; }?></p>

                <p>
                <label>
                    <span>Confirm Password :</span><input type="password"name="password">
                </label>
                </p>

                <p>
                <label>
                    <span>Email:</span>
                    <input type="email"name="email">
                </label>
                </p>
                <p><?php if(!empty($errors['email1'])) { echo $errors['email1']; }?></p>

                <p>
                <label>
                    <input type="submit"id="submit"value="Sign Up Now!">
                </label>
                </p>

                <p>
                <label>
                    <span><a href="login.html">Already member?Log in here</a></span>
                </label>
                </p>
            </fieldset>

        </form>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this block:

```
//check the errors
if(count($errors) == 0){
    //redirect to sucess page
    header('Location:login.html');
}
```

With this:

```
//check the errors
if(count($errors) > 0){
    //redirect to sucess page
    header('Location:login.html');
}
```

And also replace following line:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
```

With:

```
if ($_POST){
```

Comment: I change the  block like you provided me,it really ca redirect to login.html ..but the the information still doesnt validate,and still can store to the database directly..